# Why does unwrap_or() keep borrow in scope?

Tags: rust

Trying to compile:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let four: &mut u32 = borrow_or_add(&mut vec, 4);
}

fn borrow_or_add(vec: &mut Vec<u32>, val: u32) -> &mut u32 {
    vec.iter_mut().find(|v| **v == val).unwrap_or({
        vec.push(val);

        vec.last_mut().unwrap()
    })
}
```

[Playground](http://is.gd/TgzgBp)

...gives the following result:

```
q.rs:8:9: 8:12 error: cannot borrow `*vec` as mutable more than once at a time
q.rs:8         vec.push(val);
               ^~~
q.rs:7:5: 7:8 note: previous borrow of `*vec` occurs here; the mutable borrow prevents subsequent moves, borrows, or modification of `*vec` until the borrow ends
q.rs:7     vec.iter_mut().find(|v| **v == val).unwrap_or({
           ^~~
q.rs:12:2: 12:2 note: previous borrow ends here
q.rs:6 fn borrow_or_add(vec: &mut Vec<u32>, val: u32) -> &mut u32 {
...
q.rs:12 }
        ^
q.rs:10:9: 10:12 error: cannot borrow `*vec` as mutable more than once at a time
q.rs:10         vec.last_mut().unwrap()
                ^~~
q.rs:7:5: 7:8 note: previous borrow of `*vec` occurs here; the mutable borrow prevents subsequent moves, borrows, or modification of `*vec` until the borrow ends
q.rs:7     vec.iter_mut().find(|v| **v == val).unwrap_or({
           ^~~
q.rs:12:2: 12:2 note: previous borrow ends here
q.rs:6 fn borrow_or_add(vec: &mut Vec<u32>, val: u32) -> &mut u32 {
...
q.rs:12 }
        ^
q.rs:10:9: 10:12 error: cannot borrow `*vec` as mutable more than once at a time
q.rs:10         vec.last_mut().unwrap()
                ^~~
q.rs:7:5: 7:8 note: previous borrow of `*vec` occurs here; the mutable borrow prevents subsequent moves, borrows, or modification of `*vec` until the borrow ends
q.rs:7     vec.iter_mut().find(|v| **v == val).unwrap_or({
           ^~~
q.rs:12:2: 12:2 note: previous borrow ends here
q.rs:6 fn borrow_or_add(vec: &mut Vec<u32>, val: u32) -> &mut u32 {
...
q.rs:12 }
        ^
```

As far as I know, the body of `unwrap_or()` cannot reference the mentioned borrow of `vec`, so why is it not dropped from scope? Is there an elegant way to implement this function? I actually can't find a way to successfully do this without using two passes and a `bool` (i.e. `contains()`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The borrow is active at least for that entire statement. Unfortunately, the usual solution of pulling the `Option` out into a separate statement won't help, since it will still contain a mutable reference (in `Some`) which forces the borrow of the vector to be expanded too. This seems unavoidable when using `find()`. The compiler is worried that a pointer into the Vector's storage is floating around somewhere and would possibly be invalidated by pushing onto the vector (which could cause a reallocation). This includes not only the pointer in the returned `Option` but also ones that could be made internally by one of those functions. This would be a quite valid concern, if not for the fact that there are no "hidden" pointers and you only push when the `Option` *isn't* a pointer. The lifetime system is not fine-grained enough to capture this fact, and I don't see a simple way to repair this or work around it.

What you can do is use `position` to find an index:

```
fn borrow_or_add(vec: &mut Vec<u32>, val: u32) -> &mut u32 {
    match vec.iter().position(|&v| v == val) {
        Some(i) => &mut vec[i],
        None => {
            vec.push(val);
            vec.last_mut().unwrap()
        }
    }
}
```

Note that indices into vectors are essentially glorified pointers. They can start referring to the wrong element if the vector changes, though they can not become dangling on re-allocation and invalid indices (greater than the largest valid index) will cause a panic rather than memory unsafety. Still, getting the index from `position` and then indexing with it is only *correct* because the vector is not (substantially) modified in between.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that *you* know, by virtue of its semantics, that `vec.iter_mut().find().unwrap_or()` will ignore anything about the `vec` it comes from. However, the compiler has no knowledge of that. Indeed, the chain of method calls could very well store a value coming from the iterator, up to the closure invoked by `unwrap_or()`. See this common scenario, which has an analog structure to your example:

```
let mut vec: Vec<i32> = vec![3, 2, 5];
vec.iter().map(|&i| { 
    vec.push(i+1)
}).last();
```

Here `vec.iter_mut().find().unwrap_or()` is just replaced by `vec.iter().map()`. And as you can see, values from `vec` *can* be borrowed throughout the method call. In this latter example it is obvious how `vec.push(i+1)` would invalidate the iterator, that is why the compiler prevents it.